# Should there be The Definitive Web Development Book Guide and List?

Tags: discussion, questions

We have [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) , and also [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) . Should we have a similar list for HTML/CSS/JavaScript? It could make sense I’d suppose.

Comment: If a book is about "HTML/CSS/JavaScript", it isn't going to be any good. Like a book about "C/C++".

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: @BSMP As a result, we are asking question authors to do their own research before asking here – so they do, and they read a shitty web tutorial, or an incompetent book, and then they post a stupid question based on inaccuracies they read. There are so many worthless websites and books that claim to be competent, it is so hard for a layman (like me) to capture those few that are worthy, there seems to be a dire need for a list of worthy reads

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that it's off topic and doesn't even address the fact that these posts *attract opinionated answers and spam*.

Answer (score 10):

No, those questions are both rightfully locked. We don't need new ones.

For such lists we always had tag wiki's but now we also have [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation). That kind of lists can be incorporated in the various examples offered there.

Comment: Documentation is a example oriented site (despite its name), I'm not sure that books are examples.

Comment: That is true @Braiam slightly edited, is this acceptable?

Comment: Dunno if documentation would be able to present list-of-things in any acceptable manner.

Comment: @Braiam I think it would. Docs does a decent job at handing out teh codez that do various things with explanations - why couldn't it do the same for books given enough attention from users willing to moderate it?

Comment: @dorukayhan we are talking about list of stuff, more accurately "list of books". I have trouble linking Documentation "show by example" philosophy to "list of stuff". Personally, I don't like list of stuff. I like stuff that has a category (meta data) that I can query.