# Downvoting questions because they are based on learning resources frowned upon by the community

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

1) There is consensus AGAINST recommending or disrecommending any learning resources on SO: [Should there be The Definitive Web Development Book Guide and List?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342966/should-there-be-the-definitive-web-development-book-guide-and-list)

2) People use learning resources that are nevertheless informally frowned upon and ask questions based on what they read. Small list of examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bullschildt

3) *These questions get downvoted because the downvoter dislikes the learning resource the OP used*, which is absurd. Recent example: [python the hard way assignment ex 36. Am I just misunderstanding the instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443543/python-the-hard-way-assignment-ex-36-am-i-just-misunderstanding-the-instruction) The first comment under this question, that has already gained one upvote, reads: "–1 for Zed Shaw – wim 18 mins ago"

<my POV> SO users have NO RIGHT to judge questions on the basis of the learning resource the author used exactly because they at the same time refuse to clearly state which learning resources are accepted here and which are frowned upon and may lead to the question getting downvoted. </my POV> The question askers CANNOT know which learning resources they should use and which should be avoided.

Comment: This is what the flag button is for.

Comment: What do you propose to do with the million or so of us who vote pretty much as we please? Ban the lot of us? You can't enforce consistency among such an audience.

Comment: @JoeC the flag button is absolutely not for complaining about downvotes.

Comment: No, but in the third case, it can be used for unhelpful comments.

Comment: @gaazkam i think you being overly dramatic. For starters, I doubt wim 
 downvoted, this comment implies wim is *downvoting Zed Shaw*, and plus, the downvote came much after the comment. Regardless, this question has several reasons why it could be downvoted. For starters, there *is* proscriptions about titles, and "LPTHW Ex 36 help me solve it" is not a good title. Second, the OP should really be providing much more detail about what they are doing and what they've attempted and how exactly it is failing, i.e., providing a [mcve], in other words, being more specific and less vague.

Comment: @RobertLongson "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down None of this justifies downvoting for the learning resource used by the OP. While abusing downvotes in a way they're not designed for is not a bannable offense, it still should not be encouraged. Another example: voting to counter another one's vote: again, not a bannable offence, but still a practice widely discouraged and frowned upon on this site.

Comment: Wim is giving Zed Shaw a minus vote, **not your question**. We dislike Zed for having written such an unhelpful Python book. You have misunderstood that comment.

Comment: --1 for lack of hand drawn circles.

Comment: That's not actually a good question, so complaining about downvotes for the low quality question isn't really productive.  The question isn't clear, it's certainly too broad.

Comment: Please, *please*, **please** do not make assumptions as to why someone voted. Voting is still anonymous, and as long as there is no pattern of *targeted* voting, **anything goes**. You **can't** know if someone voted purely because the OP is asking question related to specific material or for other reasons. I strongly *doubt* anyone is voting like that, but even if they were, **that's not something we could even begin to regulate**. We are not the thought police.

Comment: The trouble is *this* question isn't actually a question.

Comment: More seriously the sample you've linked just can't stand by itself as a question so it is hard to see if anyone actually downvoted for reason that you claim rather than simply showing no-research/unclear (could be fine on special forum for whatever book that person asks for)

Comment: Is there actually a question here or did you just want to rant?  Users have the freedom to downvote whatever they want (anonymously, if they choose) and I don't see any benefit to try and restrict that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , the next time I see someone else ranting in the comments that one should not vote to reverse another one's vote, I'll direct them to this comment of yours. One example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930383/why-can-an-ifstream-be-opened-both-for-reading-and-writing#comment80807648_46930383

Comment: @MartijnPieters More seriously, I am NOT calling to make a policy banning votes depending on their intention. Rather, I believe that in spite of the (substantiated) lack of such a policy, certain patterns of unhelpful voting (like voting to reverse other's votes or voting based on the learning resource used by the OP) can be legitimately discouraged, but never banned.

Comment: @wim, see above.

Comment: I haven't read all of this yet, but I get a feeling it's a load of bullschildt.

Comment: @Will Oh - a massive one.  I'm fairly sure I have EVERY RIGHT to judge questions - the up/down vote arrows are right there, as are the close/delete buttons.  They seem to work for me just fine, so I have been granted the rights.

Comment: @gaazkam QQ here.... how do we realize why votes are cast? Stack has a mind reading machine now? Because unless we have THAT technology, it'll be VERY hard to find why people downvote..... You are right that we shouldn't encourage voting of this kind.... But.... can you show me where it says it's encouraged?

Comment: @gaazkam: we already have guidelines on voting. Hover over the arrows and you'll be given them in a tooltip. Your question wasn't asking about guidelines however, it's a rant based on assumptions that I really don't think apply here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By having the power to vote, I have the right to judge (including arbitrarily, or exercising no judgment whatsoever).  By claiming that users don't have this right, you claim that users can't vote.  This is...paradoxical.

Nonetheless, I want to call attention to the premise of your question:  **you believe users are incurring downvotes due to the fact that they use (or don't use) certain resources, or that they reference certain books.**  That is ***wrong***.  [Your sample subset](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bullschildt) contains examples where two out of three answerers *painstakingly* explained away bad writing and poor information in an effort to improve the OP's experience.

I would gladly do the same if I felt like an OP had been slighted by a bad author.  There is nothing more damaging to an engineer than being *taught* the wrong thing early on and believing that this is correct.  Helping with that is only beneficial.

The last example you cite suffers from another issue - [there are users advising against](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356700/1079354) using this reference, because it contains a lot of misleading information in it.  Them voting on that premise *alone* isn't exactly cool, but there's really not much you can do about it either from that angle.

At that point, all you can do is ***educate the OP.*** Fix their broken mental model given to them  by poor authors and bad resources.

Whether or not their initial mental model deserves a downvote, I can't really say.  Not all of us were born reading good books or having good mentors around.  Hopefully those who knee-jerk react like that would understand that.  But there's really not much you can do about it since voting is anonymous and indiscriminate *by design*.

Comment: _"arbitrarily, or exercising no judgment whatsoever"_ You may have the right as a practical matter, but that doesn't make this right. Some rights are curtailed at the point they cause harm, and this is that point for votes here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell:  So long as the votes aren't actively a *pattern* of abusive behavior, there's really nothing stopping someone from voting any which way on a question because their dog barked so loudly they clicked the down arrow, and when they calmed the dog down it was too late to undo the damage.

Comment: There's no way to stop it, but that doesn't mean it should be condoned.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's all I'm trying to say. Lol. And I'm getting comments that I'm writing "loads of bullschildt". Lol. Thank you for rephrasing me in a less heated, more concise manner than I ever could.